# php mysql pdo insert into related tables from form input

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert

three related tables: one table being the `member` table who has the ability to add into the other two  tables (actually one of the tables is a zip/city/state called `location` table, so no need to insert), but the third table is `postad` where the member can post an ad.

member is logged in and session started and is directed to the `postad` form, how can the member populate the `postad` table. the tables are:

```
member (id, username, email, address, locationId ...)
location (zip, state, county)
postad (id, title, descrip, locationId, memberId ...)
```

Here's the code:

```
$post=array('title','descrip','locationid','memberid');
foreach ($_POST as $post => $var) $$post=$var; 

if ($_POST['submitted']) {

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `postad` (`title`,`descrip`,`locationid`,`memberId`) VALUES 
(:title,:descrip,(SELECT `id` FROM `location` WHERE `id` LIKE :id AND `member.id`=:memberid))")

echo "Thank you!"; 

}
```

Comment: I don't get it, you have a `member` logged in and a `postad` table and want to insert data into it? What is the problem? Show some code of what you've tried so far

Comment: Please phrase a question. What exactly do you want? What is your current approach? At which development stage are you?

Comment: sorry. my first time here.

Comment: If your user is logged in, store his locationid and usernameid on a session and then you can avoid using that SELECT inside your INSERT.

Comment: Thanks @prix! i'll try that and when i get it working, i'll edit my post. thanks!

Comment: @mog don't forget you need to use `$stmt->bindParam` and `$stmt->execute();` as its not listed on your above code. bindParam will bind each of your prepared fields.